# Adding only one of s3 partitioned files to AWS Glue

Tags: python, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I'm having slight issues when it comes to running a crawler through my s3 buckets. My folders have data that was dumped from redshift that was sliced into many different files. These files naming convention go as the following:

dump_0000_part_00.gz,   dump_0001_part_01.gz ....

However when my crawler fetches the metadata in this folder, it instead makes a few hundred tables, thinking each one of these sliced files is its own table. Is there a way to tell the crawler to group all these sliced files into ONE catalog table?

Answer (score 0):

When configuring the Crawler (or editing an existing one), under the `Output` section, expand `Grouping behavior for S3 data (optional)` and select `Create a single schema for each S3 path`